# Running login script in Unity for 16.04

Tags: unity, permissions, scripts, login, lightdm

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 client computer that is connected to LDAP (FreeIPA). It takes its users from IPA LDAP. Accordingly, we have a mkhomedir directive in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file that creates home directory automatically.

```
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so      skel=/etc/skel/      umask=0022
```

I have written a small customization script for Unity Desktop for every user that logs in to the Desktop. Now, we want to run this script each time a user/new user logs in. Because, we want all users to see a standard Desktop.

My configuration is as below:

Login script to run:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/login.sh

#!/bin/bash
dconf reset -f /
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size 24
```

LightDM config that I have changed:

```
$ cat /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf

[Seat:*]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
greeter-show-manual-login=true
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/login.sh
```

LightDM under this config runs the script every time a user, that logged in before, logs in. But when a new user without home directory tries to login there is a login loop that directs the new user to greeter again.

After auditing we have realized that the automatically created home directory of the newly logged in user is created with ownership root:root

```
drwx------  6 root        root        4096 Jun  7 12:10 newuser/
```

This only happens if the user has never logged in before.

I tried putting session-setup-script under `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with the variations as below:

```
$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[Seat:*]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/login.sh

$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/login.sh

$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[LightDM]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/login.sh
```

Also tried to put `lightdm.conf` under `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`

None of these approaches worked. The same behavior!

As a result, when I try to run this script new users without home directories cannot login to Unity. But if the user has logged in before (home directory created with correct ownership) they can continue using Unity with the customization.

I made searches about lightdm, pam and linux logon script. But couldn't find and answer to this problem. Can anybody help what to do to create the home directory of new users with the correct permissions?

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the way to solve it. I put the script into a .desktop file and put this file under /etc/xdg/autostart/ and it worked.